# How do I invest a bounty for the greater good?

Tags: discussion, support, bounties

Suppose you want to

- earn your Altruist badge
- get rid of some rep you feel was ill-gotten (like an exceedingly simple answer that was upvoted into oblivion)
- generally spend some rep

And you don't personally have a question that you need answered. What questions in the Stack Overflow ecosystem would benefit especially from some bounty love? How do I invest a bounty for the benefit of the question & answer base?

- How can I identify those questions?
- How can I find some outside the tags I frequent?
- Are there characteristics that define those questions?
- Do you know any specific questions that could benefit from a bounty?

Comment: If the responses are good, maybe this could even be a FAQ candidate? I don't know. (Seeing as it's not really *F*AQ, I can't find any duplicates of this :)

Comment: Benefactor is a bounty awarded on your ***own*** question... I assume you mean Altruist?

Comment: @Matt ah, yeah, I mean that one. Thanks

Comment: Edit your old questions to advertise Discount Gucci Handbags and bounty them so that they can't be closed by mortals :)

Answer (score 8):

One way to find good questions without answers is going to the [Unanswered Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered) tab - it's sorted by votes count so you will clearly see questions with lots of upvotes and without answers. (Without upvoted answers, to be totally accurate)

Just sift through this list and you ought to encounter some that can use a fresh bounty.

Being heavily upvoted usually means it's good, as many people think it's good and having no answer usually means those questions are just too complicated - more the reason to place a bounty.

Answer (score 3):

```
How can I identify those questions?
How can I find some outside the tags I frequent?
```

1. There are many [unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) which can be used for investing bounty.
2. Found question which is already posted but you are interested in more specific answers.

`Are there characteristics that define those questions?`

Every tough question is eligible for bounty. Everyone had different assumptions of tough.

1. Every person will like different question to invest according to their need.
2. Question having less views.
3. Question having no answers.
4. Question having no accepted answers.

`Do you know any specific questions that could benefit from a bounty?`

I know many questions which are eligible for bounty.

1. [Go through this unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered).
2. [Questions having at least 1k views and not accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3A0+views%3A1000&submit=search)
3. [Questions having at least 10 votes and not accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3A0+votes%3A10)
4. Question with your favourite tags